# Changing a checkbox label in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, checkbox

I'm trying to change a checkbox label in Javascript. The site is Wordpress and the form is a plug in, so I have to use a snippet plug in to target the checkboxes.

In brief, when a session is full, the checkbox needs to be greyed out and the label text highlighted in red.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
var mon1 = document.getElementById('Mondays_7_1_1');
mon1.disabled = true;
mon1.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div>
<input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="5.00-6.00pm: 4-6 year olds  FULL" id="Mondays_7_1_1" /> 5.00-6.00pm: 4-6 year olds  FULL<br>
<input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="6.00-7.00pm: 7-9 year olds" id="Mondays_7_1_2" /> 6.00-7.00pm: 7-9 year olds<br>
<input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="7.00-8.00pm: 10-14 year olds FULL" id="Mondays_7_1_3" /> 7.00-8.00pm: 10-14 year olds FULL
</div>
<div style="font-weight: normal;color:red;" id="checkbox_Mondays_7_1"></div>
```

The greying of the box isn't a problem, but I can't change the font colour of the label. Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: are you able to change the font color using inspect element ? If no, then probably the css is preventing that from happening.

Comment: the text that you are trying to render is not part of the `<input>` so in short you'll have to use a different markup..

Comment: To begin with, put the "label" in a `<label>` element, and link it to your checkbox. For usability, the checkbox should be selectable by clicking on its label.

Answer (score 3):

The only way you can do this is to change your markup as the text isn't part of the checkbox. All you need to do is add labels around the checkboxes and their respective texts, and traverse to the correct label with JS.

Your checkboxes should have `<label>`s anyway, so that when the text is clicked it triggers its checkbox.

You can target the label using `parentNode`

```js
var mon1 = document.getElementById('Mondays_7_1_1');
mon1.disabled = true;
mon1.parentNode.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<label>
    <input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="5.00-6.00pm: 4-6 year olds  FULL" id="Mondays_7_1_1" /> 
    5.00-6.00pm: 4-6 year olds  FULL
</label>
<br />
<label>
    <input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="6.00-7.00pm: 7-9 year olds" id="Mondays_7_1_2" /> 
    6.00-7.00pm: 7-9 year olds
</label>
<br />
<label>
    <input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="7.00-8.00pm: 10-14 year olds FULL" id="Mondays_7_1_3" /> 
    7.00-8.00pm: 10-14 year olds FULL
</label>
<br />
```

N.B. If you intend to trigger on the checkbox change, use `change`/`onChange` not `click`/`onClick`.

Comment: That's the valid complete answer

Comment: This seems to be the only method that affects the colour of the textual element. Unfortunately it changes the 'labels' for all checkboxes within the group, even when specific code is attributed to each separate element. Is there a way to target each specific 'label'?

Answer (score 2):

This is because the Style was only for the INPUT.
I have added a label to the text for the moment.

HTML

```
<div>
    <input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="5.00-6.00pm: 4-6 year olds  FULL" id="Mondays_7_1_1" /><label id="Mondays_7_1_1-text">5.00-6.00pm: 4-6 year olds  FULL</label><br>
    <input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="6.00-7.00pm: 7-9 year olds" id="Mondays_7_1_2" /> 6.00-7.00pm: 7-9 year olds<br>
    <input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="7.00-8.00pm: 10-14 year olds FULL" id="Mondays_7_1_3" /> 7.00-8.00pm: 10-14 year olds FULL
</div>
<div style="font-weight: normal;color:red;" id="checkbox_Mondays_7_1"></div>
```

JS

```
var mon1 = document.getElementById('Mondays_7_1_1');
mon1.disabled = true;
var mon1Text = document.getElementById('Mondays_7_1_1-text');
mon1Text.style.color = "red";
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utft200o/1/)

Comment: I would suggest a `<label>` instead of a `<span>`

Comment: a label should wrap the input or have a for attribute

Comment: Nice idea Darren, but it doesn't work here I'm afraid :o(

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your text around a `<span>` for example, because it is not a part of the input.

```
<div><input class="" type="checkbox"  name="Mondays[]" value="5.00-6.00pm: 4-6 year olds  FULL" id="Mondays_7_1_1" />
<span name="Mondays_7_1_1">5.00-6.00pm: 4-6 year olds  FULL</span>
...

<script>
var monSpan = document.getElementsByName('Mondays_7_1_1')[0];
monSpan.style.color = "red";</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest a `<label>` instead of a `<span>`

Comment: Yeah sure. @Popnoodles answer is way better anyway as embedding input inside label is W3 valid.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm unaware that I have any access to the guts of the shortcodes.

Your only workaround then afaik is DOM manipulation. Something in the taste of :

```
var disableFunc = function (id, index) {

    var childNodes = document.getElementById(id).parentNode.childNodes;
    var texts = Array();
    var textIndices = Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 3 && childNodes[i].nodeValue.trim() != "") {
            texts.push(childNodes[i].nodeValue);
            textIndices.push(i);
        }
    }

    var mon1 = document.getElementById(id);
    mon1.disabled = true;
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = texts[index - 1];
    span.style.color = 'red';
    mon1.parentNode.removeChild(childNodes[textIndices[index - 1]]);
    mon1.parentNode.insertBefore(span, childNodes[textIndices[index - 1]]);
}

disableFunc('Mondays_7_1_1', 1);
//disableFunc('Mondays_7_1_2', 2); //!\ doesn't work !
//disableFunc('Mondays_7_1_3', 3); //!\ doesn't work !
```

This will work for 1 disable, because the function doesn't take into account the new modified DOM ;) http://jsfiddle.net/sskqtL9x/4/

I suggest you prepare your DOM (to match the replace pattern) by wrapping your labels inside `span`s or `label`s and then run this func after some tweaking is done to it.